# Permutations minus Transpositions

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

I want a formula that allows me to find all the permutations in $S_n$ (which is the set of all the integers from 1 to $n$) which don't contain a transposition.

**Attempt:**

Lets call $g(n)$ the formula, then $g(n)=n! - ($$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k A_{i}$$
)$, where $A_{i}$ is the set with permutations with only i transpositions.

Now I know I need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, my problem is I'm not able to count the number of permutations with exactly k transpositions.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean permutations whose cycle decomposition contains no $2$-cycles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  With the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, your result should be $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\,\frac{(-1)^kn!}{2^kk!}$, which is roughly the closest integer to $\frac{n!}{\sqrt{\text{e}}}$.

Comment: so the answer I get would be $n!(1-e^{-1/2})$ right, this doesn't agree with the answer of i have weirdly

Comment: No, that is the number of permutations whose cycle decomposition has a transposition.

Comment: isn't the value of the above just the number of permutations with a transposition, so to get the ones without don't I just subtract that from $n!$...

Comment: The $k=0$ term is the size of the whole permutation group.  It is already there.

Comment: spot on! thanks for clarifying it

Answer (score 6):

By  way   of  enrichment  here  is  an   alternate  formulation  using
combinatorial   species.   The   labelled combinatorial class  of   permutations   with  no
transpositions is

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{\ge3}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the generating function
$$G(z) = 
\exp\left(z+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$
which is
$$G(z) =
\exp\left(- \frac{z^2}{2} +\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$
or
$$G(z) =
\frac{1}{1-z}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right).$$

Extracting coefficients from this we obtain
$$n! [z^n] G(z) = n! \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2^q\times q!}
\sim n! \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}.$$